# Issues Viewing PDF's

Tags: python, interface, gtk, pygtk, glade

**Platform:** Linux, GTK+

**Tools:** Python, PyGTK and Glade.

### Problem:

- *I'd like to write a program that is capable of displaying a PDF file.*

### Question:

- *Which widget(s) and Python module(s) do I need?*

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Display it on the screen, or convert it to something else to display it?

Comment: Simply display it on the screen without launching an existing pdf viewer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look into the python poppler bindings.

I render pdf files in a simple dirty way. I copied the method used in the example for the python poppler gtk bindings

```
def load_pdf(self):
    self.doc = poppler.document_new_from_file (uri, None)
    # the number of pages in the pdf
    self.n_pgs = self.document.get_n_pgs()
    # the current page of the pdf
    self.curr_pg = 0
    # the current page being displayed
    self.curr_pg_disp = self.document.get_page(self.curr_pg)
    # the scale of the page
    self.scale = 1
    # the document width and height
    self.doc_width, self.doc_height = self.curr_pg_disp.get_size()


def render_pdf(self):
    cr = self.pdfda.window.cairo_create()
    cr.set_source_rgb(1, 1, 1)
    if self.scale != 1:
        cr.scale(self.scale, self.scale)
    cr.rectangle(0, 0, self.doc_width, self.doc_height)
    cr.fill()
    self.curr_pg_disp.render(cr)

def on_next_btn_clicked(self, widget, data=None):
    if self.curr_pg < self.n_pgs:
        self.curr_pg = self.curr_pg + 1
        self.curr_pg_disp = self.doc.get_page(self.curr_pg)
        self.render_page()

def on_prev_btn_clicked(self, widget, data=None):
    if self.curr_pg > 0:
        self.curr_pg = self.curr_pg - 1
        self.curr_pg_disp = self.doc.get_page(self.curr_pg)
        self.render_page()
```

Its not the best or prettiest but it works. I still have to add how to make it scrollable or center in the drawing area and stuff like that but there is a start.

you could also look into the evince python bindings, I do believe they have a widget you can use for to make pdf rendering easier. I'm on developing on windows so I haven't used it if there is one.

Comment: you have complete code of viewing PDF files using python ? Mind to share ?

Answer (score 0):

Not GTK but wxPython:

> This example shows a PDF Viewer class, which handles things like Zoom and Scrolling. It requires python-poppler and wxPython >= 2.8.9.

- http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577195-wxpython-pdf-viewer-using-poppler/

Answer (score -1):

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ghostscript/

Comment: I don't think googling for "python ghostscript" is beyong anybody's abilities should the link go stale.